# How to POST or PATCH users role and access_level for BIM360 on Postman

Tags: postman, patch, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have been successful in creating a new `Account User` from following this tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-POST/#example, and have used the `PATCH` method to set their status to `active` on Postman.

I would like to set their `role` and `access_level` but I am having trouble doing so. I have followed the link below to try and perform this function, but it requires the user to already be a `BIM 360 Project Admin` for it to work.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-user_id-PATCH/

I also tried following the next link below to add a User to a project, but I am getting errors that I am unsure how to fix.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/

**URI:** `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v2/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id/users/import`

**Method:** `PATCH`

**Authorization:** *******************************************

**Content-Type:** `application/json`

**x-user-id:** `{{user_id}}`

**Body:**

```
{
  "email": "john.smith@mail.com",
  "services": {
  "document_management": {
      "access_level": "account_admin"
    }
  },
  "company_id": ************************************,
  "industry_roles": [
    ************************************
  ]
}
```

(The id for `industry_role` is IT).

**Error:**

```
{
  "code": 1004,
  "message": "this user doesn't exist."
}
```

I am unsure how I am getting this error since the User Id used for `x-user-id` is the same `user_id` associated with the `email` given in the request body. Is there a way to fix this or another method I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The `x-user-id` header is not for specifying the user to import but rather:

> x-user-id
>   string
>   In a two-legged authentication context, the app has access to all users specified by the administrator in the SaaS integrations UI. By providing this header, the API call will be limited to act on behalf of only the user specified.

Remove this field if that's not what you intended.

Verify the `user id` and `email` match each other via [/GET users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/) and [/GET users:userid](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-:user_id-GET/).

And be sure to provide either the user's email or the user ID and don't provide them both:

> Note that you need to specify either an email, or a user_id. However, you cannot specify both.

See doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/#body-structure)