# Postman - How to Import Users to a BIM 360 Project Using the V2 Endpoint

Tags: c#, postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am working on a small .NET Console App that uses the BIM 360 API to manage both Project and Account members using the two-legged authentication method. I am having trouble trying to import users to a BIM 360 Project using the [hq/v2/accounts/:account_id/projects/:project_id/users/import](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST) endpoint.

In both a .NET Console App and Postman, I receive a 404 status code with the following body response:

```
{
    "code": 1004,
    "message": "this user doesn't exist."
}
```

**Request Header**:

```
Content-Type: "application/json";
x-user-id: "********-****-****-****-************";
Authorization: Bearer ****<two-legged token string>*****;
```

(**x-user-id** is the guid assigned to the account admin)

**Request Body**:

```
{
  "user_id": "********-****-****-****-************",
  "services": {
    "project_administration": {
      "access_level": "admin"
    },
    "document_management": {
      "access_level": "admin"
    }
  },
  "company_id": "********-****-****-****-************",
  "industry_roles": []
}
```

In the request body, I have used both the `user_id` fetched from the [hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/users/:user_id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-:user_id-GET/) `id` property, and the `email`. I have used a user who is already a member of the project, a user who is in the Admin directory but not a member of the project, and a completely new user who is neither. All three still return the same error.

I've came across similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909554/how-to-post-or-patch-users-role-and-access-level-for-bim360-on-postman) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757659/import-users-to-bim-360-project-using-forge-v2-endpoint) but still can't get it to work.
Is there something else I am overlooking? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: might be better to ask this on autodesk's forums I would think.

Comment: what's the format of the `user_id` you are passing? it should be in the form of o `[A-Z][0-9]`, and not a GUID-like

Answer (score 0):

The `user_id` property of your payload and `x-user-id` header need to be user's `uid` rather than the user's `id`.